# REST API call with AWS Signature Version 4 (cannot sign AWS API requests)

Tags: bash, rest, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I've never been able to get AWS API calls to work.  I am trying to work on a Linux server on my network to issue REST APIs to interact with my enterprise AWS account.

I am trying to sign AWS Requests with Signature Version 4.  Do I need to do this on an AWS instance?  I have the shared access key, the RSA private key (begin RSA private key... end RSA private key), and the AWS Access key (e.g., the AKAI... value).

The problem I have have trouble with is creating the canonical request.  I get an error "Malformed URL."  Bash parses my curl but has a problem with the parameter after this:

`curl -i ... -X GET / action=listusers` ...

I am trying to follow these directions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

I think my command should work because the above link shows this as an example canonical request:

```
GET
/
Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:iam.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

This has many parameters.  A curl command to the above canonical request would result in an error about a "malformed url" and a bash command not recognized with this line:

```
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

The above directions do not explain how to determine the URI.  How do I determine the URI?  How do I use long curl commands with correct parsing of the URI so I do not get a space between the arguments to invoke Bash's response about an unrecognized command?

I have tried many permutations of curl commands to list the servers or users associated with my AWS account.  Nothing seems to work.

I want to issue a basic API command to verify it works.  I'd love to list the AWS instances or list the users associated with the AWS account.  But I am stuck at creating a canonical request because apparently I do not know how to determine which URI or URL to use in a Curl command.  If I knew how, I could sign requests.  If I could get Linux curl commands to work, I could eventually use Python's subprocess to invoke them.

Comment: You're pretty far off track, I'm afraid.  You don't actually pass the canonical request to curl at all.  That's not why you create it.  The canonical request is a string that **describes** the request you are going to make, using a *canonical* (known, fixed, formalized, standardized) format.  This string becomes the core of the message that you use to generate the signature.  You make a normal `curl 'https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=...'` request.

Comment: Now I want to start with the basics.  How do I create the curl command?  What URL do I use?  I have a few EC2 servers (but they have no public DNS name and no public IP address).  I'd like to list either the servers or the users in the AWS account.

Comment: In the example from the page you mentioned, it would be `curl 'https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE%2F20150830%2Fus-east-1%2Fiam%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150830T123600Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-amz-date'`

Comment: Ugh, there seems to be a bug in comment handling markdown.  There should be no spaces in the URL above, but otherwise it appears to be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Too late to give my answer, however it could be useful for others who want to find a sample bash to invoke AWS API Gateway Rest that support AWS Signature version 4. The sample script can be found here: https://github.com/riboseinc/aws-authenticating-secgroup-scripts

Comment: That's pretty cool. I also created a full bash script to create a signature for AWS signature version 4 in case anyone wants a standalone script: https://gist.github.com/adrianbartyczak/1a51c9fa2aae60d860ca0d70bbc686db